# Running into problems on ios with get_storage

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

Why, when I add get_storage to my project, my project doesn't run on ios anymore, and at the same time

Warning: CocoaPods minimum required version 1.10.0 or greater not installed. Skipping pod installation.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to yours
plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.

It gives this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.